# Jacobi symbol continuity

Tags: number-theory, profinite-groups

I am working on the following exercise in a syllabus by Lenstra.

[image]

After having solved the first parts of the exercise, I am stuck at the last part of proving that $\mathbf{Q}^\times \times \widehat{\mathbf{Z}}^\times\to \{\pm 1\},(a,n)\mapsto \left(\frac{a}{n}\right)$ is continuous (and bimultiplicative).

Proving the continuity is equivalent to finding the preimage of $1$ and proving this is open. However, it seems to me that is very difficult to explicitly state what this preimage is.

Could someone please provide any help?

Comment: what is $\hat{\mathbb Z}^*$?

Comment: The units in the ring of profinite  integers.

Comment: How did you show that $\lim_i (\frac{b}{n_i})/(\frac{c}{n_i})$ converges?